# Interactions between categorical terms in GAM (mgcv)

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to fit a model using the `mgcv` package and I need to include interactions between categorical terms. I know how to implement interactions between continuous and categorical variables as:

```
s(x1, by=c1)
```

but I don't know how to change this for two categorical terms and I couldn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: if it is just two categorical variables and not including any smooth terms then add the interaction in the usual way `c1*c2`

Answer (score 4):

You can add parametric terms to the formula just as you would in a linear model or a GLM.

```r
gam(y ~ f1 + f2 + f1:f2 + s(x1), data = df, method = "REML")
```

or via the shorthand

```r
gam(y ~ f1 * f2 + s(x1), data = df, method = "REML")
```

would be a model with main effects plus interactions of the two categorical variables `f1` and `f2` plus a smooth effect of continuous variable `x1`.

Anything you can do with parametric terms in `lm()` or `glm()` can be used in the formula for `gam()`, `gamm()`, `bam()`, and `gamm4::gamm4()`.